# In android studio am I able to hide and show a label/textview? if so what would i use?

Tags: java, android

Is there a thing like textview visibility on and off. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the XML you can set `android:visibility="invisible"` or "`visible`"
In the Java code you can type `YourTextView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: Please correct your mistyped at `YourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. You missed the `i` in `bility`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `android:visibility="visible"` for setting visibility in *xml*. The options are `visible|invisible|gone`.

Or `textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in code.

More info here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)